# Tweepy API: how to get a user's id from a status SearchResult object?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to write a script to follow people on twitter.  The tweepy API seems pretty good, but I'm running into some unintuitive behavior related to the mapping from user's ids to their screen names.

```
In [1]: import tweepy
In [2]: api = tweepy.API()

# get an arbitrary tweet
In [3]: tweet = api.search("anything")[0]

In [5]: tweet.text
Out[5]: 'Currently mourning the [potential] loss of around 500 pictures I took while in Oklahoma. Anyone know anything about Canon Rebels?'

# who tweeted it?
In [6]: tweet.from_user
Out[6]: 'helloregan'

# get the tweeters id
In [7]: tweet.from_user_id
Out[7]: 101962792

# i'm paranoid. just want to make sure its right.
In [8]: helloregan = api.get_user(user_id=tweet.from_user_id)           

# yep, same id.
In [9]: helloregan.id
Out[9]: 101962792

# lets check to see if its the same screen name? no. different person.
In [10]: helloregan.screen_name
Out[10]: 'kikiiputh'
```

What gives?

Answer (score 7):

Figured out the issue isn't a tweepy one:
http://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=214

Updated for reference for any other tweepy users who run into the same issue.